# Form with 2 datagridviews, how to mantain their proportion when the form is resized?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with 2 group boxes and in each one datagrid with 3 buttons. I tried using anchor and docking and it works but not as I would like. I want to mantain the proportion of form space that is occupied by each groupbox. So when I resize the form it shoud look similar to as it looks now. 
From what I could see the anchor resizes right groupbox as much as possible and the left one is resized only to the left border of the right groupbox.
Any help?
[image]

Comment: Use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview)

Comment: Or SplitContainer

Comment: Yes, I would dock.fill them in a splitcontainer with a fixed slider.

Comment: Panels and docking are your friend here. Use them together with a SplitContainer for this case

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, I used both Table Layout Panel and Split Container.